# Emails disappeared from Inbox

Tags: gmail, google-search, gmail-archive

A couple of days ago, all of my mail disappeared from my Gmail inbox.  I do not know if I accidentally removed it (I don't think so) or if some problem occurred at Google.  Is there a way to search for mail which was archived during a certain time period?  I just would like to know which emails were in the mailbox just before the emails were archived.

Comment: Related: [How do I see a list of archived emails in Gmail in the order of when I archived them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126147/88163)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to search by messages when they were Archived. ("Archive" just means "remove the special 'Inbox' label.)

The best you'll be able to do is to search by date range for when the messages were dated.

More importantly, though, you should check that there's not something nefarious going on. Gmail doesn't just do that "because". It's possible you've created a filter which acts on more messages than you anticipated. If that's not the case, make sure it's not some other third-party app "helping" you. Check your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com) to see what app you have connected to it. Check also that someone hasn't created a filter you don't recognize. Check the recent activity to see if someone logged in from an unfamiliar location. (It would be a good idea to take the security check-up at "My Account".)

One other possibility: If you visited or tried out Inbox by Gmail and snoozed all of your messages, they'll be temporarily removed from the Inbox label in Gmail.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think I could search by "last timeframe a label was changed"  I do not think anything nefarious is going on or that some third-party app removed the Inbox label, but I will keep an eye out.  This is the first time this has happened to me in over 12 years of using GMail.  Just to be safe, I ran the security checks and changed my password.  I already use 2 step authentication.  I regularly sign out of all connected devices using the Details link at the bottom of the Gmail page.

Comment: It's possible when you use inbox.google.com instead of mail.google.com, but it isn't called archived, it's called done or something like that…