# How do I see a list of archived emails in Gmail in the order of when I archived them?

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

The "Done" view in Inbox by Gmail (sunsetting in March 2019) allows me to review my recently archived emails, in the order I archived them (with the most recent at the top). Is there a search I can run in Gmail to get the same list?

Inbox even groups the emails by when you archived them: "Today", "Yesterday", "This month" etc. so Google must be storing the timestamp of when they were archived and therefore I'm hoping there's a way to sort my search using that timestamp. Even just getting the emails I archived today would be helpful.

I reviewed Google's [article about advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190), but don't see anything relevant.

Note: I'm not asking how to see archived emails, I know that I can click on "All Mail".

Comment: See also https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/can-i-see-only-mail-i-have-archived-in-gmail

Comment: @RingØ that question seems to be asking “how do I see archived mail only”, I’m asking “how do I see archived mail only, sorted by when it was archived”.

Comment: I comprehended that aspect... But being able to *only* view archived mails is a good start. Well, that was merely an informative comment, and certainly not 100% relevant to the question. Now, considering that "archiving" is actually just removing the (usually) "inbox" label, I doubt the "archiving time" is even existing anywhere, let alone be available to the end user. (it's not an "Archive" folder as in many other mail clients). Btw there are many extensions available, and maybe one does this, or actually processes archiving in a special way (or you could program it!).

Comment: I agree it’s related. Regarding google having this info, I explained why I think they would in the question (basically it worked in inbox).

Comment: It looks like you may be able to recover the data using the API: [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list])https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching `in:archive` sorts by archival date.

[Medium article about recovering archived emails](https://medium.com/@MattGyverLee/oops-i-just-archived-a-bunch-of-gmail-messages-71aae70322d7):

> To search for recently archived emails in Gmail, open Gmail and in the
> search box, type “in:archive” (without the quotes) and press enter. It
> will show only messages that have been archived (not including
> messages in the inbox like All Mail).
>
> The magic of this command is that now the dates of the messages
> represent the date of archival (not the date of receipt)! The results
> should already be sorted by date that the message was archived.

Comment: While this works well on desktop web, I've noticed that this doesn't work on iOS (tried both the Gmail app and mobile web) - the search returns no results.

Comment: ...nor does it work on mobile app in Android.

Comment: Thanks! On my wife's email it autocompleted this to `in:archives` and then switched it to `label:archives` so if the above doesn't work, try that instead.  (Note: no space before or after the colon)

Answer (score -2):

There isn't. In Gmail are all archived emails under **All Mail** folder, which contains all archived emails as well as everything else. Best you can do is search for: **`-in:inbox`** which could get you what you need, however not in the order you archived your messages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of how to view Archived emails (added to my question) - I want them in order though. I'm pessimistic that there's a way to do this, but I still wanted to ask.

Comment: @JBallin answer updated

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't solve my issue of wanting them in order, it's just another way to see my archived mail.